# Windows Server 2016 Quota Per User on Folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

I would like to know if it is possible to set a **quota per user** at the **folder level** in Server 2016?

I already know it is possible to set a quota per user at the volume level using the quotas in volume properties, and it is possible to set a quota for a folder in File Server Resource Manager, but this method is an overall quota for the folder - not per user. I already know this much. My actual question is above this paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a quota per user AND per folder.

User-Quotas can be set at volume level and size-quotas can be set at folder level. Everything above that would make the ntfs peoply cry. Very loud.